# How to convert List<dynamic> to List<T> without getting warning from linter in Dart?

Tags: dart

I wrote this code to convert dynamic list to `Word` list but linter says:

`Omit type annotations for local variables.` on 2nd line.

However if I omit type annotations, I get an error `A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be returned from method 'convert' because it has a return type of 'List<Word>'.`

It there any smarter way to convert?

```
  static List<Word> convert(List<dynamic> words) {
    final List<Word> wordsList = [];
    words.forEach((v) {
      final map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(v as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);

      wordsList.add(Word.fromMap(map));
    });
    return wordsList;
  }
```

---

Word.fromMap is:

```
  Word.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : text = map['text'] as String,
        count = map['count'] as int;
```

Comment: What type of argument does `Word.fromMap` take?

Comment: @julemand101 Thank you for your comment. It takes `Map<string, dynamic>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the warning, and put the type on the right-hand side as the lint wants, just write:

```dart
final wordsList = <Word>[];
```

I assume words is JSON data, so the maps are already `Map<String, dynamic>`. Then you can also do everything in one line:

```dart
  static List<Word> convert(List<dynamic> words) => 
      [for (var v in words) Word.fromMap(v)];
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding <Word> erased the warning!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`cast()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/cast.html) method like this:

```
class Word {
  final String text;
  final int count;

  static List<Word> convert(List<dynamic> words) {
    final List<Word> wordsList = [];
    words.cast<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>().forEach((v) { // <-- look here
      final map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(v);

      wordsList.add(Word.fromMap(map));
    });
    return wordsList;
  }

  Word.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : text = map['text'] as String,
        count = map['count'] as int;
}
```

It will ensure the casting are done on each element. Make sure the type are correct since it will else result in a type-cast error.

Comment: Thank you it worked but still anger in `final List<Word> wordsList = []`.  